# Excel Table columns erroneously added after I delete a column and refresh table

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a table that is populated by a DAX query and a connection with my workbook's data model.  I added an additional calculated column into my table and when I refresh the data everything updates fine.  The headers look something like this:

[image]

CAT1 is the calculated column.  I no longer need CAT1.  When I delete it and refresh my table, a new column is automatically created that is just a repeat of the left-most column, as shown here:

[image]

I've tried avoiding the issue by deleting the column within the table, deleting the column by deleting the entire excel worksheet column, moving the column I'm trying to delete to the right of the table then adjusting the table range so it doesn't include the column, and looking around in the excel table and external properties but have had no luck.

Any ideas of what's going on here and how to fix things?